# Jenkins Dashboard of Pipeline steps

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, dashboard

I'm using the pipeline plugin (with pipeline stage view) on Jenkins and I want to know if a plugin can make a dashboard of the stage view information as the dashboard plugin does for jobs.

Comment: anyone to help me ?

Answer (score 2):

I am looking for the same dashboard too, I just want to show all pipelines by stages view on one page.

Most close is this.

https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-aggregator-view-plugin

[image]

And,

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Delivery+Pipeline+Plugin

[image]